# Correct timezone handling with TYPO3 and Fluid

Tags: mysql, datetime, typo3, fluid

Its confusing me. I've a property in my Model which is annotated with DateTime. In my Database its stored as timestamp. In Frontend I use the f:format.date viewhelper to output this property.

When I create a new record, and add f.e. 01.06.2017 10:00 in this field, in my database is stored the timestamp for 01.06.2017 08:00. In Frontend the output is correct. Until here everything is fine.

The last timechange in March lead to a + of two hours in output. I assume in October that will change again and the output will be than this: 01.06.2017 08:00.

How can I prevent this. Its definitely a problem when these dates change, because its important for the business.

How can I test what will happen in October?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521073/how-can-i-avoid-datetime-problems-in-typo3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem occurs as TYPO3 saves times normalized as UTC. for normalization (and afterwards denormalization) it respects the timezone-settings of the server. Or settings given in LocalConfiguration.php.
Up to 6.2 there were two settings `[SYS][serverTimeZone]` and `[SYS][phpTimeZone]`.
With 7.6 it is only `[SYS][phpTimeZone]` as the servertimezone is detected from php itself.

You now have the option to fake the timezone of your server to "UTC" by setting `[SYS][phpTimeZone]` to the string "UTC". In this way no times should be changed any more.

Comment: Even not in summer or wintertime? :-)

Comment: UTC has no daylight saving time (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/timezone/utc). so all times stay as entered.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 9.5 and newer

Use the environment ([documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html?highlight=timestamp))

```
// use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
// use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context;       
        $context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
        // Reading the current data instead of $GLOBALS
        $currentTimezone = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('date', 'timezone');
        $currentTstamp = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('date', 'timestamp');
        $current = new DateTime('@'.$currentTstamp);
        $current->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($currentTimezone) );
```

In Fluid you may use a DateTime-Object:

```
// in PHP-ode of Viewhelper
//...
        $this->registerArgument('date', 'mixed', 'Either an object implementing DateTimeInterface or a string that is accepted by DateTime constructor');
// ...
```

In HTML

```
 {dateTimeObject -> f:format.date()}

<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">{dateTimeObject}</f:format.date>
```