# TYPO3 - TCA - Datetimeformat

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Typo3 6.2, working on my personal extension.
I'm using a flexform with this TCA :

```
'eventdate' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'Date of event :',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval'     => 'datetime',
        'checkbox' => '0',
        'default'  => time(),
    ),
),
```

... and my SQL field is a DATETIME, sample from my ext_tables.sql :

```
CREATE TABLE xxxxxxx
(
    eventdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
);
```

Problem : when saving, the generated field format by Typo3 is **hh:mm:ss dd:mm:yyyy** but in my SQL table the datetime format is **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**, then it makes an error when user try to save in the backend :

> 1: These fields are not properly updated in database: (eventdate)
>   Probably value mismatch with fieldtype.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `int DATA TYPE` is the best way to store DATE in tstamp format in DB.

You need to define eventdate DATA TYPE like below

```
CREATE TABLE xxxxxxx
(
    eventdate int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The TCA configuration of the original question misses the `dbType` property which instructs TYPO3 during saving data in `DataHandler` to use a different time format (the default format is unix timestamp which is normalized to UTC).

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Input/#dbtype for details (the documentation is for TYPO3 7.6 but worked since TYPO3 6.0 as well).

**ext_tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE tx_myextension_xxxxxxx (
   eventdate DATETIME default NULL
)
```

**TCA field configuration**

```
'eventdate' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'Date of event:',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval'     => 'datetime',
        'dbType'   => 'datetime',
        'default'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ),
),
```

- removed `checkbox` which is superfluous for type `input`
- adjusted default value to `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`
- added `dbType` property

**Side note for TYPO3 v8**

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#rendertype-inputdatetime which shows the new render type for `datetime` values that can be used in TYPO3 v8.

Comment: I used `'default'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to display default date on `starttime` field. but after saving I find that the time is reduced by one hour on this filed

Comment: Please make sure PHP [`date.timezone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) is set correctly. TYPO3 backend has additional [`serverTimeZone` & `phpTimeZone` settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863345/correct-timezone-handling-with-typo3-and-fluid)